# Transforming a dataset in a more compact format (Stata)

Tags: database, stata

initially I was dealing with a dataset that looked something like this:

```html
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
| date |  geo   | variables | value |
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
| 1981 | Canada | var1      | #     |
| 1982 | Canada | var1      | #     |
| 1983 | Canada | var1      | #     |
|  ... | ...    | ...       | ...   |
| 2015 | Canada | var2      | #     |
| 1981 | Canada | var2      | #     |
| 1982 | Canada | var2      | #     |
|  ... | ...    | ...       | ...   |
| 2015 | Canada | var2      | #     |
| 1981 | Quebec | var1      | #     |
| 1982 | Quebec | var1      | #     |
| 1983 | Quebec | var1      | #     |
|  ... | ...    | ...       | ...   |
| 2015 | Quebec | var2      | #     |
| 1981 | Quebec | var2      | #     |
| 1982 | Quebec | var2      | #     |
|  ... | ...    | ...       | ...   |
| 2015 | Quebec | var2      | #     |
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

So I have 35 time periods, two countries and two variables. I would like to transform the table in Stata for it to look like this:

```html
+------+--------+------+------+
| date |  geo   | var1 | var2 |
+------+--------+------+------+
| 1981 | Canada | #    | #    |
| 1982 | Canada | #    | #    |
|  ... | ...    | ...  | ...  |
| 2015 | Canada | #    | #    |
| 1981 | Quebec | #    | #    |
| 1982 | Quebec | #    | #    |
|  ... | ...    | ...  | ...  |
| 2015 | Quebec | #    | #    |
+------+--------+------+------+
```

However, I'm not having much success with this. I tried to separate the different observations into variables with the command:

```
separate value, by(variables) generate(var)
```

Which creates something like this:

```html
+------+--------+------+------+
| date |  geo   | var1 | var2 |
+------+--------+------+------+
| 1981 | Canada | #    | .    |
| 1982 | Canada | #    | .    |
|  ... | ...    | ...  | ...  |
| 2015 | Canada | #    | .    |
| 1981 | Canada | .    | #    |
| 1982 | Canada | .    | #    |
|  ... | ...    | ...  | ...  |
| 2015 | Canada | .    | #    |
| 1981 | Quebec | #    | .    |
| 1982 | Quebec | #    | .    |
|  ... | ...    | ...  | ...  |
| 2015 | Quebec | #    | .    |
| 1981 | Quebec | .    | #    |
| 1982 | Quebec | .    | #    |
|  ... | ...    | ...  | ...  |
| 2015 | Quebec | .    | #    |
+------+--------+------+------+
```

Which contains a lot of useless missing values.

So, more specifically, I would like something to bring me directly to Table A to B (i.e. without using `separate`), or a solution to fix Table C into B.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without sample data, my answer will have to be untested. I think something like the following will get you started in the right direction.

```
reshape wide value, i(date geo) j(variables) string
```

Note that this assumes the contents of your `variables` variable are suitable for use as variable names. For example, a value of `1potato` for variables would be a problem.

In any event,

```
help reshape
```

should be your first stop.

Added in response to comment: Here is some data I made up and a demonstration that `reshape` works for this data. Perhaps you can explain how this data differs from the real data. Your error message suggests that for some combination of date and geo, a particular value of variables occurs more than once.

```
. list, sepby(geo)

     +----------------------------------+
     | date      geo   variab~s   value |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 1981   Canada       var1     111 |
  2. | 1982   Canada       var1     211 |
  3. | 1983   Canada       var1     311 |
  4. | 1981   Canada       var2     112 |
  5. | 1982   Canada       var2     212 |
  6. | 1983   Canada       var2     312 |
     |----------------------------------|
  7. | 1981   Quebec       var1     121 |
  8. | 1982   Quebec       var1     221 |
  9. | 1983   Quebec       var1     321 |
 10. | 1981   Quebec       var2     122 |
 11. | 1982   Quebec       var2     222 |
 12. | 1983   Quebec       var2     322 |
     +----------------------------------+

. reshape wide value, i(geo date) j(variables) string
(note: j = var1 var2)

Data                               long   ->   wide
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                       12   ->       6
Number of variables                   4   ->       4
j variable (2 values)         variables   ->   (dropped)
xij variables:
                                  value   ->   valuevar1 valuevar2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rename (value*) (*)

. list, sepby(geo)

     +-----------------------------+
     | date      geo   var1   var2 |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. | 1981   Canada    111    112 |
  2. | 1982   Canada    211    212 |
  3. | 1983   Canada    311    312 |
     |-----------------------------|
  4. | 1981   Quebec    121    122 |
  5. | 1982   Quebec    221    222 |
  6. | 1983   Quebec    321    322 |
     +-----------------------------+

.
```

Comment: Hi, I'm perfectly willing to provide some sample data, but I don't know how to do this. And I tried your suggestion, which gave me the following error message: `values of variable variables not unique within date geo`. And, for the record, before asking this question, I tried all possible combination of the `reshape` command, without success.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You're right, it should work. So this means there is something wrong with the data. Can I send you the .dta file in question? A possible problem I see is that instead of "var1, var2,..." the names present in "variables" are rather lenghty and contain spaces. Can that cause the problem? Otherwise, how can I check if, as you say "that for some combination of date and geo, a particular value of variables occurs more than once"? Thanks again.

Comment: This is a different question, you should ask in another thread (might be duplicates though)

Comment: The `duplicates` command will help locate duplicates, which you will then have to decide what to do with, and the `strtoname()` function may help with the variable names. I would `rename value v_` before the `reshape wide` to try to make sure the new variable names created by `reshape` don't exceed 32 characters.

Comment: There was indeed a single traitorous duplicate. Thank you for your help.